# trying to create array reader for feature fields

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, ext-js, array

I am trying to create a functionality that creates array data for any layer that user selects. Now I am able to get all the data in the feature layer that the user selects but I am having some trouble with the `ArrayReader` to which I need to assign the field names of the feature data.

So this is field collection loop,

```
for (var prop in e.features[0].attributes) { attrfields.push(prop); }
```

As of now I am hard coding the `ArrayReader` like this,

```
var myReader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({},[
                    {name: 'family'},
                    {name: 'species'}
                ]);
```

I need to replace,

```
[{name: 'family'}, {name: 'species'}]
```

with the `attrfields`, which looks like this,

```
[Object {"Family"}, Object {"Species"}]
```

Now am confused as to how I should create `attrfields` to replace it in the `ArrayReader`? Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution, http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?245126-Dynamically-assigning-titles-to-Ext.grid-columns

I needed to create the columns fields separately and then add the attrfields to the `ArrayReader`.